# Error after adding new listener on android

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have launched a simple publisher on my linux pc with ros and then i tried to modify the pubsub tutorial to show messages published by ros machine on the phone screen. Logcat informs me that subscriber was succesfully registered but there are also some errors. In the end nothing appears on my android device screen. Could you help me resolve this problem?

Here is code:
MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends RosActivity {

  private RosTextView<std_msgs.String> rosTextViewPublikowanie;

  public MainActivity() {
    // The RosActivity constructor configures the notification title and ticker
    // messages.
    super("Pubsub Tutorial", "Pubsub Tutorial");
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    rosTextViewPublikowanie = (RosTextView<std_msgs.String>) findViewById(R.id.text_publikowanie);
    rosTextViewPublikowanie.setTopicName("publikowanie");
    rosTextViewPublikowanie.setMessageType(std_msgs.String._TYPE);
    rosTextViewPublikowanie.setMessageToStringCallable(new MessageCallable<String, std_msgs.String>() {
      @Override
      public String call(std_msgs.String message) {
        return message.getData();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  protected void init(NodeMainExecutor nodeMainExecutor) {
    NodeConfiguration nodeConfiguration = NodeConfiguration.newPrivate();
    nodeConfiguration.setMasterUri(getMasterUri());
    nodeMainExecutor.execute(rosTextViewPublikowanie, nodeConfiguration);
  }
```

and a Listener

```
public class Listener extends AbstractNodeMain {

  @Override
  public GraphName getDefaultNodeName() {
    return GraphName.of("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/listener");
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart(ConnectedNode connectedNode) {
    final Log log = connectedNode.getLog();
    Subscriber<std_msgs.String> sub_publikowanie = connectedNode.newSubscriber("publikowanie", std_msgs.String._TYPE);
    sub_publikowanie.addMessageListener(new MessageListener<std_msgs.String>() {
      @Override
      public void onNewMessage(std_msgs.String message) {
        log.info("I heard: \"" + message.getData() + "\"");
      }
    });
  }
```

and Logcat

```
05-15 01:23:24.439: E/dalvikvm(23345): Could not find class 'java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue', referenced from method org.jboss.netty.util.internal.QueueFactory.createQueue
05-15 01:23:24.439: W/dalvikvm(23345): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2378 (Ljava/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue;) in Lorg/jboss/netty/util/internal/QueueFactory;
05-15 01:23:24.479: E/dalvikvm(23345): Could not find class 'java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue', referenced from method org.jboss.netty.util.internal.QueueFactory.createQueue
05-15 01:23:24.479: W/dalvikvm(23345): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2378 (Ljava/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue;) in Lorg/jboss/netty/util/internal/QueueFactory;
05-15 01:23:24.539: I/Registrar(23345): MasterXmlRpcEndpoint URI: http:/----/
05-15 01:23:24.599: I/Registrar(23345): Registering publisher: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</android_gingerbread/ros_text_view, http:/----/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
05-15 01:23:24.909: I/Registrar(23345): Response<Success, Registered [/android_gingerbread/ros_text_view] as publisher of [/rosout], [http://Salon-Linux:42216/]>
05-15 01:23:24.909: I/DefaultPublisher(23345): Publisher registered: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</android_gingerbread/ros_text_view, http:/-------/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>>
05-15 01:23:24.939: I/Registrar(23345): Registering subscriber: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</publikowanie>, TopicDescription<std_msgs/String, 992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1>>>
05-15 01:23:24.959: I/Registrar(23345): Response<Success, Subscribed to [/publikowanie], [http://Salon-Linux:42897/]>
05-15 01:23:24.969: I/DefaultPublisher(23345): Subscriber registered: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</publikowanie>, TopicDescription<std_msgs/String, 992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1>>>
05-15 01:23:25.029: E/UpdatePublisherRunnable(23345): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Salon-Linux
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62731/error-after-adding-new-listener-on-android/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe it's quite late to answer my own question but i've forgotten about it...

The problem with UnknowHostException was connected with wrong ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI setup.

The problem `Could not find class 'java.util.concurrent.LinkedTransferQueue'` persisted but it didn't have any influence at how program worked that time. Later it has just disappeared with further development but I am unable to tell why.

---

Originally posted by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) with karma: 141 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0